# Redirect to the same page with retrieved values from database in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**View Code:**

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"  id="versiontab" 
onclick="window.location='{{ url("versiondb") }}'" >Version 
 Database</a></li>
```

This is my view code.This is also a tab .Onclicking the tab the url redirection works.

**Route Code:**

```
Route::get('versiondb','versiondbController@select');
```

**Controllercode:**

```
public function select()
{

    $users=debModel::all();
    return redirect()->back()->with($users);

}
```

Here it should fetches the values from db and redirecting back to the same page and display the retreived values in table .But i am getting an error here as **$users undefined**

**Inside the Same view (specified above):**

```
 <table class="table" id="table">
      @foreach($users as $users)
        <thead>
          <tr class="header">
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Versions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="2%">Supported versions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="10%">Release Date</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Type</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="10%">Description</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Actions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Downloader</th>
              <!--<th valign="middle" width="3%">Beta code</th>-->

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>{{$users->versions}}</td>
            <td></td>

            </tr>
          @endforeach
            </tbody>

                </table>
```

I think this is the place where error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "->with" in Laravel, Laravel go back to that page with a session message named with.
 Usiing with in your scenario would be

```
public function select()
{

$users=debModel::all();
return redirect()->back()->with("message","I generated all users");
```

}

which would be accessed in your blade as

```
@if (session('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
             {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
 @endif
```

The solution to your question is write it this way

```
public function select()
{

$data['users']=debModel::all();
return view("viewdeb",$data);
```

}
then your blade you will need a foreach loop

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  {{$user->firstname}}
@endforeach
```

mind you, more data can be sent back to the view by just including them in the data array

```
public function select()
{

$data['users']=debModel::all();
$data['business']=businessModel::all();
return view("viewdeb",$data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `($users as $user)` instead `($users as $users)` here

```
@foreach($users as $user)
```

And in your template

```
<td>{{$user->versions}}</td>
```

Also change in your controller

```
return view('haghwayUpdate')->with('users',$users);
```

Comment: But when I redirect it to the some other page and trying to display the contents it works.

Comment: So, my suggestion is error might not be with $users

Comment: @nishanthi : change in your controller `    return redirect()->back()->with('users',$users);`

Comment: @nishanthi : what is your view name  ?

Comment: Try like `return view('haghwayUpdate')->with('users',$users);`

Comment: **haghwayUpdate**  is my view name SIR!!

Comment: Tried with that.But it is not working. The same error occurs **(2/2) ErrorExceptionUndefined variable: users (View: /var/www/html/GemProdMang/resources/views/haghwayUpdate.blade.php)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
@foreach($users as $users)
```

here your array variable name and the variable in which you are holding the data on each iteration is the same, so change it to:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <td>{{$user->versions}}</td>
```

Comment: But when I redirect it to the some other page and trying to display the contents it works.

Comment: So, my suggestion is error might not be with $users